# Is there any way to get system messages such as "joined the group" using telebot?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I want to get messages about joined users and delete them. I tried to do this by getting `message.new_chat_members` but it didn't work. There is no errors in console, just nothing.

---

---

Answer (score 0):

```
    def delall(message: types.Message):
        bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
```